# How to add a space before and after conditional operator in a string?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have a string e.g "**number1<=number2&&number3>number4||number2=number4**" and having operator list as -

```
var operators = new List<string> {"=", "!", "<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=","||","&&"};
```

So, expectation is to introduce a single space before and after each operator in the string.

"**number1 <= number2 && number3 > number4 || number2 = number4**"

I tried following code but its not working for instance, e.g, <, >=

```
public static string AddSpaceBeforeAndAfterOperator(string expression) {
  var operators = new List<string> {"=", "!", "<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=", "||", "&&"};
  foreach (var op in operators) {
    var index = expression.IndexOf(op, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (index >= 0) {
      if (expression.Substring(index - 1) != " ") {
        expression = expression.Insert(index-1, " ");
      }
    expression = expression.Insert(index + op.Length + 1, " ");
    }
  }
  return expression;
}
```

Note: The Operator list is coming as random.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could construct a regex by "(" + string.Join("|", operators.Select(Regex.Escape)) + ")" and then doing a regex.Replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a regex solution.

First, you need to escape all your operators, join them together with `|`:

```
var operatorsString = string.Join("|", 
    operators.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Select(Regex.Escape).ToArray()
);
// OrderByDescending here because we want the longer operators to be matched first.
```

Next, create the regex:

```
var regex = $"\\s*({operatorString})\\s*";
```

Using the `operators` array in the question, the array looks like this:

```
\s*(<=|>=|!=|==|\|\||&&|=|!|<|>)\s?*
```

Note that `\s*` is used to check if the operator is already surrounded by spaces. If it is, those spaces will be matched and replaced.

The replacement is:

```
 $1
```

Code:

```
Regex.Replace(input, regex, " $1 ");
```

Note the leading and trailing space.

Also note that `Regex` is inside the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FAcA5l/2)

Comment: Probably, a better choice `\s*` instead of `\s?` for "if the operator is already surrounded by spaces" (what if we have *several spaces*: `"a___>=__b"`?)

Comment: @Sweeper - Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is the most effective way to do this, but is is rally simple by using replace

```
public static string AddSpaceBeforeAndAfterOperator(string expression)
{
    var operators = new List<string> { "=", "!", "<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=", "||", "&&" };
    foreach (var op in operators)
    {
        expression = expression.Replace(op, " " + op + " ");
    }

    return expression;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, But this is not going to work in case of a scenario like "number1<=number2" it will end up returning "number1 <  = number2" which is not correct